# Sublime Text autocomplete function with variable in parentheses?

Tags: php, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

If I already have this written

```
$company_id = isset($_POST['cid']) ? $_POST['cid'] : null;
```

And I want to wrap a function call around `$_POST['cid']`, is there a way to put that inside the autocompleted function's parentheses?

Instead of me typing this:

```
$company_id = isset($_POST['cid']) ? Validate::isId()$_POST['cid'] : null;
```

and then having to erase the right parenthesis, is there a shortcut to wrap the param when sublime autocompletes the function for me?

```
$company_id = isset($_POST['cid']) ? Validate::isId($_POST['cid']) : null;
```

Using Mac Yosemite and SublimeText 3.

Comment: select `$_POST['cid']` and enter left parenthesis, it will automatically closes with right parenthesis at the end

Comment: @Thamizhan Yes, but when it autocompletes the function it puts both parentheses at the end, and doesn't wrap the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `snippet` that accepts a `SELECTION` argument:

[image: SnippetDemo]

---

#### Save The Code Below @:

`Packages/___Your_Snippet_Folder___/SnippetName.sublime-snippet`

```
<snippet>

<tabTrigger>testFunction()</tabTrigger>
<description>testFunction</description>

<scope>source.php</scope>

<content>
testFunction(${1:$SELECTION}, ${2:PlaceHolder_2})
</content>

</snippet>
```

---

The use of placeholders, for example: `${1:placeholder_text_goes_here}` , allows you to assign descriptive pre-selected regions throughout your snippet that can be navigated with <kbd>Tab</kbd> & <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd>

---

Additionally, you can replace one of the placeholders with `$SELECTION`, for example: `${1:$SELECTION}` , which will pass the currently selected text as an argument if you execute the snippet from the `command palette` or a `key-binding`.

---

To insert the snippet:

- select the text to be passed as the `$SELECTION` argument
- use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> to launch the command palette
- type `Snippet:`  followed by the value of the `<description>` key in your `sublime-snippet` file

---

For more information on snippets, see:

#### [SublimeText / Unofficial Docs / Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Comment: Didn't think of adding a snippet. Great suggestion. Although, I'd probably not assume that there is a second argument, and change the `<content>` to this: `${2:functionName}(${1:$SELECTION})` if that's possible?

Comment: @GreeKatrina: `testFunction(${1:$SELECTION})` would work. You only need to use the `${#:placeholder}` segments if you want to be able to select & navigate that particular text with the tab key.